# Where does Factory come from?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto, asp.net-3.5, excel-2010

I am trying to add items to splitbuttons and galleries. The issue is with the Factory. In the following OfficeRibbon code file Factory is unknown. It is also unknown in the addin code file.  I am missing a reference somewhere. I have also tried Globals.Factory still unknown.

```
RibbonButton rc = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
```

I have the following using statements.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
//using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Extensions;
```

This code also fails in the ThisAddin.cs which has been renamed to ReqCommon.cs in my project.

My desired end goal is to dynamically add items to these two controls. Examples i have found here and elsewhere all seem predicated on this elusive Factory.

The project does reference Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v9.0.dll

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonfactory.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.factory.getribbonfactory.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the [Ribbon Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386089.aspx) - it will automatically create this **Factory** for you (`Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory()`) - otherwise you need to create your own **Factory** by [overriding `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608623.aspx) in `ThisAddin.cs` (*your ReqCommon.cs*)

```cs
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{  
    Ribbon1 tempRibbon = new Ribbon1();
    tempRibbon.tab1.ControlId.ControlIdType = Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlIdType.Office;
    tempRibbon.tab1.ControlId.OfficeId = "TabHome";
    return Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory().CreateRibbonManager(new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.IRibbonExtension[] { tempRibbon });   
}
```

The **Ribbon Designer** inherits from [`Ribbon.RibbonBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbase.aspx) which contains the property [`RibbonBase.Factory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbase.factory.aspx) which enables `this.Factory` to be used within it.

Comment: In case I broke the project, I created a new Excel addin in VS2010 added a ribbon(not XML). Then tried your code: Factory and IRibbonExtension cannot resolve. I have followed the links you provided and it looks like it should work. I don't know why this is different. If any of this matters, I have VS2010 ultimate, office 2010 64bit, on Win7 Pro.

Comment: For `IRibbonExtension`, you must be missing a reference to `Office.dll` - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office12\Office.dll`. For `Factory`, you must be missing a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll` from `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.dll`

Comment: **Not with .NET 3.5** Factory doesn't exist in the 3.5 version. I was able to get this to work with @SilverNinja's method. In order to do it I created a new **.NET 4.0** Office Addin. This is key.

Comment: Great catch and thanks for posting back! It seems **Factory** was added in **VSTO 4** codebase and is not present in **VSTO 3**. As proof... [`RibbonBase`'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbase.aspx) *other versions* do not go back past **VS 2010**.

Comment: Additional info:  The visual ribbon designers do not appear to be compatable. :( Simply switching the target .NET version from 3.5 to 4.0 will not yield positive results. IMO the best course of action is: Recreate a new 4.0 addin from the Visual Studio template and bring your code forward.